# バックスラッシュ（\）を入力すると円記号（¥）が表示されてしまう

Tags: python, macos

MacBook Pro の日本語キーボードタイプを使っています。

`\` を入力したいのですが、コマンドプロンプト以外だと `¥` と表示されます。
どうすればウェブ上などで `\` と表記されますか。

`\` と `¥` だと結果に違いが出ます。`\` の方の結果が正しいです。

---

- **`\` を使用した場合:**

  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
- **`¥` を使用した場合:**

  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>¥</kbd> で入力できるはずです。

Comment: \   できました！有難うございました。

Answer (score 4):

コマンドプロンプトでバックスラッシュが入力できているのであれば、特になにも変更する必要はありません。Macにおけるバックスラッシュと￥記号にはややこしい問題が絡んでいるのですが、今回の場合は、単にフォントが異なっているだけで、文字としてはコンソールのバックスラッシュとWebページでの入力の￥記号はおなじ文字です。

バックスラッシュと￥記号は同じ文字で、フォントの違いによって見え方が変わります。これが1つ目のややこしいところです。

Macの場合、さらに別の文字でも半角の￥記号があります。文字的にはこれは通貨文字というもので、バックスラッシュとは異なります。これが2つめのややこしいところです。

今回は、コンソールでバックスラッシュが入力できているので、おそらく1つめの方の問題でしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。質問に画像を一枚追加したんですが上の画像のように\と¥だと結果が違ってきます。\の方が正しい結果です。どのようにすれば\が入力できますか？今はとりあえずコピーアンドペーストで表示させています。

Answer (score -1):

使っているブラウザの等幅フォントの設定をいじっているのではないでしょうか。
バックスラッシュで表示されるフォントに変更すると直るのではないかと推測しました。

たいていは見え方が違っているだけで、そのままでも実行に問題ないとは思いますが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ブラウザの等幅フォントの設定をいじった覚えはないですがどのようにすればフォントの変更方法を教えていただけたら助かります。　　今回は実行結果に違いがありました。

Comment: 実行結果に違いがあるならこの回答は的外れでしたので、回答そのものはお気になさらずにお願いします。

Comment: 日本語入力に何を使っているかによりますが、Google日本語入力やOSの日本語入力を使っているなら ¥キーを押した時に ¥ を入力するか \ を入力するかは日本語入力の設定で選べますよ。それを設定するのがいいと思います。