# Windowsのjupyter notebookでスラッシュ"＼"の半角を正しく表示したい

Tags: python, python3, windows, jupyter-notebook

Windows10でanaconda→jupyter notebookで＼の半角が出ないです。
また”!”ビックリマークも紫色になり、"指定されたパスがみつかりません"となります。

*(9/27修正加筆：↑ビックリマーク"!"についてですがこれはpip install openpyxlの前に

つけた場合にエラーになりますので、ビックリマーク"!"は記号自体のエラーではないことが

判明しました。お騒がせしました。

こちらは自分で充分に調べても分からなかった場合、残念ながら新質問に代えて投稿します。

お騒がせしました。(__))*

初心的な質問で恐れ入ります。

**＼の半角が出ないことについて**

今まで試したことは、ネットなどで散見される以下の私見要約１）と２）になります。
しかし解決しませんでした。

１）
”\”の入力方法：IMEを半角モードにしてキーボードの「ろ」キーを押すとバックスラッシュを入力できます。
または、全角モードで「ろ」キーを押して、「F10」キーで半角に変換し入力できます。

[環境設定が必要]
メモ帳で、書式→フォントから書体を以下のいずれかに変更します。というネットの記述がありました。

- Arial
- Verdana
- MigMix1P
- Calibri

しかしそれはこのメモ帳に限っただけのことであって、他のアプリなどでは違う反応になります。
要するに＼の半角ではなく"￥"円マークになります。

２）
コマンドプロンプト等で半角のバックスラッシュを使いたいときは、パソコンの内部的には、半角のスラッシュと逆スラッシュは同じ文字として扱われるそうなので、そのまま半角のスラッシュを使っていても良いそうです。

**参考**
https://find366.com/windows10-keyboard-back-slash/

こちらも試してみましたが同じ扱いとして反映されませんでした。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: "半角のバックスラッシュ" に関してはフォントの問題で、見た目が `¥` なだけでそのままでOKなはずです。 / 関連質問と回答: [¥ と表示されてしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/36572)

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみたところ、¥で\に代替されました。

Comment: cubickさんへ　1/2の質問にいただいたということで回答ではなくコメントに書いていただいて恐縮です。1/2→1/1の質問に変更になりましたのでcubickさんの回答で終わりにしたいと思います。もしお気づきでしたらお手数なのですが同じことを回答欄に書いていただけますか？私の方で完了いたします。

Comment: この記事が参考になるでしょう。[Jupyter Notebookでバックスラッシュを表示する](https://qiita.com/ictsr4/items/f297bec2e6419d77b63c)

Comment: kunifさん、ありがとうございます！2~3日以内に試してみてフィードバックします。

Comment: kunifさん、私ではありませんが指示された文を人に助けていただき同様の方法で￥を\に代えられました。ありがとうございました。よかったら最終回答を同じ文でしていただけますと終了できます。いかがでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

システム全体の設定を変えるなんてことも出来なくはないでしょうが、それは一般的では無いですし何か一部だけ変えると整合性が取れなくなる可能性もあります。

以下は意図せず変わってしまった例。
[Windows10 キーボード言語設定の変更方法](https://tabletpcnavi.com/windows10-keyboad/)

> 最近実はキーボードで通貨記号の半角の￥マークが入力できないという事例にあたってしまいます。

---

そのためメモ帳で試されたのと同様に、それぞれのアプリケーションに固有の設定機能によって変更することになります。
ただしアプリケーションに機能が無ければ変えることはできません。

jupyter notebookの場合は以下の記事が参考になるでしょう。
[Jupyter Notebookでバックスラッシュを表示する](https://qiita.com/ictsr4/items/f297bec2e6419d77b63c)

> Jupyter Notebookに個人用のcssを作成することで、バックスラッシュを表示できるようにしてみました。まず、テキストエディタで次のようなcssを作成します。
>
> ```
> .CodeMirror pre, .output pre {
>   font-family: Arial,ＭＳ ゴシック;
> }
> ```
>
> このときfont-familyの1番はじめに、"arial"のような欧文フォント（日本語のひらがなや漢字が使えない）を指定します。次に、C:\Users\(自身のアカウントのフォルダ).jupyterのフォルダに"custom"というフォルダがなければ新規に作成します。そして、custom.cssというファイル名で保存します。
>
> jupyter notebookを表示するcssは別にあり、customer.cssがあれば優先して適用されるだけなので、上手く行かなくても、このcssファイルを削除してしまえば問題ありません。

---

つい最近、`stylus`を使うという別の方法?の記事が公開されました。
こちらでも出来るようなら、どちらにするかはお好みで。
[Google Collab や Jupyter Notebook でバックスラッシュを表示させたい](https://qiita.com/haruyan_hopemucci/items/e119d60618f7998bc822)

Comment: kunif様、コメントありがとうございます。